# Capybara & Cucumber - feature with expected controller exceptions fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I recently switched to capybara 2.5.0 & webkit 1.7.1.

I have a cucumber feature in which I want to **check my javascript handling of a failed ajax request**.

**With previous capybara version:**

- I stubbed an API request to respond with 400 thus the controller action raised this exception (`RestClient::BadRequest`) without rescuing it.
- My javascript was showing a custom message in case the ajax request failed.
- The feature didn't fail when the exception was raised by the controller, the flow was continuing normally. The ajax request failed and my js was handling it as expected.

**With the new capybara version:** The feature fails when the exception takes place at the controller level.

I don't want the feature to stop at that level but to continue with the error response to the browser so I can handle the error with my js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess this behavior change isn't because of the capybara update, but rather because you moved the web_console gem out of the test group.  That meant exceptions were never actually being raised in the server because web_console caught them all.  Now that exceptions aren't being caught Capybara is displaying them.  Capybara has the Capybara.raise_server_errors setting to enable/disable that behavior.

Capybara.raise_server_errors = false